# Mirroring two sharepoint libraries

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I have an existing SharePoint library with files and nested folder structure , that needs to sync with the another SharePoint library as same as source library. And also, I need to apply the rules to stop in syncing in some cases, where the files have certain format of text prefix to the file names.

Can someone help how to achieve this in MS Flow?

Comment: does Site 2 need documents only in Read Only mode? Do you need to sync one way or both ways?

Answer (score 0):

We can use flow to copy a file from one library to another, or delete a file when the same file is deleted from another library, but we will have to do it separately.

Please see the sample flows below:

**Create:** (Modified trigger)

[image]

**Delete:**

[image]

Reference:
[Flow: SharePoint Library sync.](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/power-apps-power-automate/flow-sharepoint-library-sync/m-p/1013583)

Comment: Thanks for your response. But it will work when a file is created or modified in root folder i.e nothing but library Name. My requirement is to sync file when a file is created or modified under nested sub folders as well. Is there any way?

Comment: @tarun Yes, sorry for the mistake. You can change the trigger to “When an item is created or modified” and type the library name in List Name as a custom value. I’ve tested and it works for nested sub folders as well.

Comment: @tarun I've modified the first screenshot in the answer.