# Large Items Sync Document Libraries between 2 Sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library

With no access to OneDrive, is there a way to sync (prefer automatically) Document Library 1 (with large items and subfolders) from SharePoint Site 1 to Document Library 2 in SharePoint Site 2?

Users can only access SharePoint Site 2, NOT SharePoint Site 1; I am able to access Site 1 as administrator, Site 2 as owner.

Comment: Can you simply grant users access to the Documents library from site 1? This will avoid the whole overengineering and sync nightmare.

Comment: I wish I can. But external party is not allowed to access site 1.

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, this is impossible to achieve. You must have access to Document Library 1, otherwise synchronization cannot be performed.

Suppose the user has Read permissions to Document Library 1 and Edit permissions to Document Library 2. So, you can create Microsoft Flow to sync these Document libraries.

Comment: Hi, thanks for advice. I have access to Site 1 and 2. But, users can only access Site 2. How do I use Power Automate to sync with large items and size in 100GB?

Comment: Hi EchoDu_MSFT, I found something related: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/280532/mirroring-two-sharepoint-libraries/298651?noredirect=1#comment315934_298651. But, there are some issues with this, 1) as I am not able to autosync the subfolder, the file only appeared in Site 2 in root folder; 2) if I change the file name in Site 1, instead of replace in Site 2, it was copied as another new file in Site 2.